# What is the simplest way to convert a const char[] to a string in c++

Tags: c++

Is there a simple way of creating a std::string out of an const char[] ?

I mean something simpler then:

```
std::stringstream stream;
stream << const_char;

std::string string = stream.str();
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`std::string` has multiple constructors, one of which is `string( const char* str );`.

You can use it like this:

```
std::string myString(const_char);
```

You could also use assignment, if you need to set the value at some time later than when the variable is declared:

```
myString = const_char;
```

Answer (score 11):

std::string has a constructor that takes a const char*, so you can just do:

```
const char* charArray;
std::string str(charArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
std::string str = const_char;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the std::string constructor.  You can pass it a char*:

```
char* charArray = "My String";
std::string stdstr( charArray );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert it **without creating an additional variable**, such as passing an argument to a function in just one line, try this:

```
std::string() + const_char
```

This creates an empty string using `std::string`'s default constructor and concatenates your `const char[]` or `const char*` to it to result in type `std::string`.